# Trolls and ESL folks

Tags: discussion, trolling

[This question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/144962/584) about a specific instance of offensive language in the workplace seems to have been overrun by trolls and/or folks who sincerely don’t understand the nuances of the language used. Given the ridiculous takeaway that the OP ended up with — as evidenced by the highly downvoted answer they accepted — I feel like we’ve done a disservice to the world for hosting this conversation. Is there anything that could have been done to salvage this without turning it into a language lesson?

Comment: Unless the world doesn't understand what the downvotes and upvotes mean for this question and answer, I don't think we have done a disservice at all. You understood which answer was ridiculous. Let's give credit to others that they can understand it too.

Answer (score 11):

The SE protocol answer:

"Someone accepted a super downvoted answer" - there's nothing to do about that. Some people want their position justified and will accept a highly downvoted position if it backs them up.  That's life.

You can downvote the bad answer, of course, to make the situation clear.

You can flag comment threads for deletion, as the only "overrunning" is in the comments which is why people should use comments for their intended purpose on SE sites and not for random discussion.

To answer a question about appropriate language in the workplace, however, you have to make it a little bit of a "language lesson" by its nature so I'm not sure that's a problem.

For anyone genuinely confused or ESL:

While "chinky" is a word it is not commonly used nor is it used to refer to eyes, the only time you'd expect to hear it is about a chinky window or sidewalk or something. Everyone knows slanted or almond-shaped eyes are a distinguishing feature of Asians and "chink" is a slur against Chinese folks, and any reference to "chinky eyes" is 100% saying "they have eyes like them Chinese folks." Anyone who *does* know English but says there's plausible deniability here either has severe personal problems with social cues or is straight out being an apologist for racism.

Comment: To add to this action, you don't need to be a native speaker to understand that answer as ridiculous. Provided the link with the definition and knowing that it is a racial slur and it is considered offensive, you just put 2+2 together...

Comment: That's a fair point, have added info to my answer about the actual content in this question.

Comment: Usually the ESLs are the ones who are going to call the racists on their BS because somebody is going to ask "What is chink?" sooner or later - sooner if they're in a circumstance they cannot freely google something up